# How to call a controller method with multiple parameters in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api 2 with a controller name sendSms.
Here is the code of sendSms controller:

```
 public class sendSmsController : Controller
    {    
        public string Get(string id, string pass)
        {
            return id + pass;
        }
    }
```

i want to call this method from browser.
here is the routes configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "api", routeTemplate: "api/{sendSms}/{id}/{pass}", defaults: new { });
        }
```

and here is how i call this api:

```
http://localhost:8979/api/sendSms?id=1&pass=2
```

but its giving me Server Error (Resource Not Found).
can anyone help me to sort this out?

Comment: Have you tried to call it with the route you specified: http://localhost:8979/api/sendSms/1/2?

Comment: @JanneP it gives me this error:<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8979/api/sendSms/1/2'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:8979/api/sendSms/1/2'
</MessageDetail>
</Error>

Comment: Try decorating your method with [HttpGet("api/{sendSms}/{id}/{pass}")].

Comment: your routing is completely wrong (that part, that you added, I mean), and, as I can see, you don't understand how it's working. You need to read more about this convention-routing. Or use attribute-routing, as @JanneP, suggests (needs a lot of reading anyway, because just attribute is not enough). Btw, suggested attribute is wrong:)

Comment: @JanneP suggested attribute is not working..

Comment: @vasily.sib can you help me with routing in this case?

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 describing attribute routing in Web Api 2. Even if you're not going to use it. It helps understand how routing is to be configured.

Comment: @UsmanFarooq ok, but promise me that you read about how routing works:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about routing. This is a key-point of your web application. For now, here is 2 solutions:

**Convention-routing way:**

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

SendSmsController.cs:

```
public class SendSmsController : Controller
{
    public string Get(string id, string pass)
    {
        return id + pass;
    }
}
```

**Attribute-routing way:**

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

SendSmsController.cs:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/sendSms")]
public class SendSmsController : Controller
{
    [Route]    
    public string Get(string id, string pass)
    {
        return id + pass;
    }
}
```